# wifi and hdmi problems on OS X yosemite (macbook pro 15-inch retina, late 2013)

Tags: wifi, macos, macbook-pro, hdmi

Just wondering if anyone has been having this issue and found a workaround:
My wifi works consistently both on Ubuntu and Android.
Sometimes it also works on OS X, other times it does not - not even after rebooting. No idea what's the problem.

I also have problems with its HDMI output (random pixels being displayed on the external screen). Again, Ubuntu works fine with the same TVs.

Answer (score 1):

At least the wifi issue should have been fixed (but it wasn't) with the latest update:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably that the MacBook is closed while connected to the external display and the antennas aren't transmitting right. Try opening the MacBook and the Wi-Fi problem should be fixed.

Comment: it shouldn't influence really, as antennas is normally located in the hinge that connects the screen and rest of the body.

Comment: No the problem is that the case and screen are blocking the signal. I've had this problem myself

Comment: hm, cool, it sounds like some edge case and bad positioning, Daniele.. I intentionally checked on Mac, the signal from this spot is weak (1 bar only), closed lid with external monitor, and open internal display - haven't made any weather, it's still 1 bar shown and you can work.

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I can tell you for sure that it worked for me